# Running an javascript function before an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to run the first ajax call when it has completed run the function "saveToFile()" and after that has been completed run the second ajax call. Doesn't seem to work as coded. I'm fairly new to ajax so am struggling a little with this one.

```
// save composition to database 
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "_inc/save_to_db.php", 
    data: {jsonStr: canvasStr}, 
    success: function(data) {
            // this saves the comp to the _comps folder on the server as a jpeg file (firth.js)
            saveToFile();

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST".
            url: "_inc/generate_thumbnail.php",
            data: {imgFile: "<?php echo $_SESSION['UserID'] ?>_<?php echo $_SESSION['CompID'] ?>.jpg"},
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you share `saveToFile`?

Comment: If it is a asynchronous function then you need to use a callback to sent the second ajax request

Comment: You _need_ this: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me: http://jsbin.com/upujur/2/edit

The problem might be with the dot instead of comma in this line:

```
type: "POST".
```

Are you using a JavaScript console like FireBug or Developer Tools to debug your program?

Answer (score 1):

You could make the `saveToFile` function take as parameter a callback which will be executed once the AJAX call it performs is finished. For example:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "_inc/save_to_db.php", 
    data: {jsonStr: canvasStr}, 
    success: function(data) {
        // this saves the comp to the _comps folder on the server as a jpeg file (firth.js)
        saveToFile(function(result) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "_inc/generate_thumbnail.php",
                data: {imgFile: "<?php echo $_SESSION['UserID'] ?>_<?php echo $_SESSION['CompID'] ?>.jpg"},
            });
        });
    }
});
```

and your `saveToFile` function may now look like that:

```
function saveToFile(successCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: ...,
        type: ...,
        data: ...,
        success: successCallback
    });
}
```